# Pass the variable `Nothing` using Python's `win32com`

Tags: python, vba, win32com

I am trying to pass the variable `Nothing` in VBA using Python's `win32com`. I tried to use `None` but it returned 'Type dismatch.'

Could anyone please help?

Thank you!

An example:

```
' Book1.xlsm!Module1
Function test(arg As Object) As String
    If arg Is Nothing Then
        test = "Success"
        Exit Function
    Else
        test = "Failure"
        Exit Function
    End If

End Function
```

And in Python:

```
import win32com.client
import os
import pythoncom


xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = True
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=os.path.abspath('Book1.xlsm'))
test_str = xl.Application.Run('Book1.xlsm!Module1.test', pythoncom.Empty)
```

The REPL says:

```
runfile('C:/Users/shwang/Downloads/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/shwang/Downloads')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-22-301693920f2c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/shwang/Downloads/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/shwang/Downloads')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/shwang/Downloads/untitled0.py", line 16, in <module>
    test_str = xl.Application.Run('Book1.xlsm!Module1.test', pythoncom.Empty)

  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 14, in Run

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 287, in _ApplyTypes_
    result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352561), None)
```

Comment: Did you pass `None` or `'None'`?

Comment: You might be able to use `pythoncom.Empty`. See [this message](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2009-February/008826.html)

Comment: Also http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/36145/pythoncom.Missing

Comment: Can you create a small example we can try? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterWood Thank you so much! I added an example. And I tried but neither `pythoncom.Empty`, `None` or `'None'` seem to work.

Comment: You could add a VBA function that returns Nothing, i.e. have a factory function that's purpose is to generate a Nothing; call that from Python; store result in a variable and then pass that variable.

Answer (score 2):

In VBA, `Nothing` is used as the uninitialized default value [`Object` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dim-statement) which usually references COM objects (i.e., Excel object library or external application's object library). VBA's primitive integer, long, and string types cannot be assigned the *Nothing* value. And usually programmers use this at the end of code block to release objects from memory.

Hence, there is no strict translation between VBA's `Nothing` (a special value for COM types) and Python's value types including `None` which crudely means empty or no value for *any* type.

With that said, your code will not err out if you pass a COM object which you already initialize with `xl`. Below outputs `FAILURE`. If somehow you can declare an uninitialized COM object which then will carry *Nothing* then you can pass that into your function. But to call `Dispatch` requires a named object. Catch-22!

```
import win32com.client
import os

try:
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    xl.Visible = True

    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=os.path.abspath('Book1.xlsm'))
    test_str = xl.Application.Run('test', xl)
    print(test_str)
    # FAILURE

    wb.Close(False)
    xl.Quit

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    wb = None
    xl = None
```

Comment: Thank you Parfait! I see the logic there. Too bad that I am using the SolidWorks API (a 3D CAD software) that requires `Nothing` as an input argument for certain purposes. I guess I can wrap it with VBA code and call the wrapper instead whenever `Nothing` is needed - not pretty but doable. Thanks again!

Comment: Default value of a Variant is Empty.

Comment: Thank you @SMeaden. Per [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/variant-data-type), you are correct and so I removed any mention of `Variant` as Excel COM objects would not even use this type.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example (in python) that passes VBA Nothing object to SolidWorks API.

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
swApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('SldWorks.Application')
Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("", "SKETCHCONTOUR", 75e-3, -4e-3, 0, False, 0, pythoncom.Nothing, 0)
print(boolstatus)
```

Here is the output in Sublime Text 3:

> True
>
> [Finished in 0.7s]

The script tries to select a sketch contour with the coordinates (75mm, -4mm). The "Callout" argument of the SolidWorks API "SelectByID2" is assigned as pythoncom.Nothing. For the script to work, the premise is that you are editing a sketch as shown in the attached figure below.

The attached figure shows what happens in SolidWorks (before | after).

### [Pass Nothing to SW API SelectByID2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPSu1.png)

Some background. I want to draw some electric motor geometry in SolidWorks via python because I already have the working python codes with other drawing tools (such as JMAG Designer, FEMM, or PyX).

**Thanks for the post! Your discussion helps me find this.**

Comment: You could add a VBA function that returns Nothing, i.e. have a factory function that's purpose is to generate a Nothing; call that from Python; store result in a variable and then pass that variable.